# Why is my new string value undefined in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, undefined

I'm building a shopping cart in React.js and I have everything working as it should be. Along with existing string values such as price, description, title and image I wanted to add an SKU value. In my `cartReducer.js` file, I have the following:

```
import Item1 from './images/apple_gala.jpg';
import Item2 from './images/apple_greenleaf.jpg'
import Item3 from './images/apple_granny.jpg'
import Item4 from './images/apple_pinklady.jpg'
import { ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_ITEM } from '../actions/action-types/cart-actions.js'

const initState = {
    items: [
        {id:1,title:'Royal Gala', desc: "Gala apples have a blush of pink in their skin. It’s dense, sweet juicy flesh makes it ideal for eating fresh.", price:7,SKU:A,img:Item1},
        {id:2,title:'Greenleaf', desc: "Our own original produce, the Greenleaf Original apple is award winning for the crispness of it's skin.",price:8,SKU:B,img: Item2},
        {id:3,title:'Granny Smith', desc: "Our French Granny Smith apples have a distinct sharp taste – perfect for eating fresh or using in cooking.", price:5,SKU:C,img: Item3},
        {id:4,title:'Pink Lady', desc: "A distinct and refreshing flavour with uniquely pink colouring - it can only be our Pink Lady apples.", price:5,SKU:D,img: Item4},
    ],
    addedItems:[],
    total: 0

}
const cartReducer= (state = initState,action)=>{

    if(action.type === ADD_TO_CART){
          let addedItem = state.items.find(item=> item.id === action.id)

         let existed_item= state.addedItems.find(item=> action.id === item.id)
         if(existed_item)
         {
            addedItem.quantity += 1 
             return{
                ...state,
                 total: state.total + addedItem.price 
                  }
        }
         else{
            addedItem.quantity = 1;

            let newTotal = state.total + addedItem.price 

            return{
                ...state,
                addedItems: [...state.addedItems, addedItem],
                total : newTotal
            }

        }
    }
    if(action.type === REMOVE_ITEM){
        let itemToRemove= state.addedItems.find(item=> action.id === item.id)
        let new_items = state.addedItems.filter(item=> action.id !== item.id)

        let newTotal = state.total - (itemToRemove.price * itemToRemove.quantity )
        console.log(itemToRemove)
        return{
            ...state,
            addedItems: new_items,
            total: newTotal
        }
    }

  else{
    return state
    }

}

export default cartReducer
```

inside the items array I have 4 items, to the far right I have the newly added SKU values, simply ABCD. When I save the file I get a failed to compile error as A, B, C and D are all undefined. The weird thing is the other string values aren't defined anywhere either, so why are the SKU's failing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where have you defined the A, B, C variables? You are using them as variables here instead of strings. You need to put them in quotes to make them a string literal.

```js
{id:1,title:'Royal Gala', desc: "Gala apples have a blush of pink in their skin. It’s dense, sweet juicy flesh makes it ideal for eating fresh.", price:7,SKU:"A",img:Item1},
```

That's why you are getting this error only on the SKU

Comment: As if I forgot the quote marks to define the value as a string, thank you for spotting this for me - must be getting code brain after a long day. Will mark as correct answer when I can thanks!

Comment: No problem, it happens from time to time. Try to keep a close eye on the errors you get, sometimes I stop reading the error codes as closely and it bites me in the end too.